# How can I display the Build number and/or DateTime of last build in my app?

Tags: c#, winforms, build, version, versioning

I know that I can do this to get the app's official (release/publish) version number:

```
string version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();  
this.Text = String.Format("Platypi R Us - version {0}", version);
```

...but this only shows a "Publish version" of my app* ("1.0.0.0"). I want to show the build number.

- From the Project | Properties | Publish tab.

Barring that, or in addition to that, I'd like to show the date and time of the last build, so that it says *"Platypi R Us - version 3.14 (7/17/2012  16:22)"*

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1488918/127837

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate at all - he wants what I don't want (to show the release version number). I can do that (and am doing that at present), but I want a build number, so that I can verify a user is running the most recent build that I've deployed.

Comment: Are you referring to the file version of the assembly?

Comment: The Version is made up of 4 numbers: Major, Minor, Build, and Revision.  Rafael's link shows how to auto-increment it to give a unique value per build.

Comment: @Rafael: Anything to differentiate one from another; I'll take another look at that link, as I didn't at first see what John mentions.

Comment: Using System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.get_CurrentDeployment(), I get: "System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException was unhandled Message=Application identity is not set. Source=System.Deployment" - apparently that trick only works for ClickOnce deployment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The value returned from `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` is that in your project's AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Modify these before a build to specify the value it returns.  Or, as documented in the same AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```