# How do I get the last write or build time of my app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display the Build number and/or DateTime of last build in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532705/how-can-i-display-the-build-number-and-or-datetime-of-last-build-in-my-app)

I want to append the last DateTime of when my app was built to the titlebar. But this code:

```
DateTime lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().ToString());
this.Text = String.Format("Platypi R Us; Built on {0}", lastWriteTime);
```

...claims that was over 400 years ago (in the year 1600); I find that unlikely.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532705/how-can-i-display-the-build-number-and-or-datetime-of-last-build-in-my-app

Comment: @zeroef: No, but a similar one; I gave up on including version info, as that is just something like "1.0.0.0" and a build number is not available. So I am now settling for a "last built time" value, which is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've called `GetLastWriteTime` using something which *isn't* a filename. Print out `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().ToString()` and you'll see what I mean.

The [documentation for `File.GetLastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx) calls this out specifically:

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

So, either use [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx) as per Clay's suggestion, or for a specific assembly (or to avoid a WinForms dependency), you could use [`Application.ManifestModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.manifestmodule.aspx) and get the [`FullyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.fullyqualifiedname.aspx), like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string file = typeof(Test).Assembly
                                  .ManifestModule
                                  .FullyQualifiedName;
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        DateTime lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
        Console.WriteLine(lastWriteTime);
    }
}
```

Of course, that only gets the last write time of the module containing the assembly manifest - it's possible to have multi-module assemblies. It's rare though, and my guess is that this will do you fine.

It's a shame that there *isn't* a concept of a build time embedded within `Assembly` itself, but such is life :(

Comment: Interesting that the documentation gets the date wrong, not that it matters (it shows 1600, not 1601).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath);
DateTime lastWriteTime = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
this.Text = String.Format("Platypi R Us; Built on {0}", lastWriteTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

'GetName()' returns the display name of the assembly. You want [Assembly.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx)

Also, I'm not sure this will work. If you copy the file to a different location then the file time is out-of-sync with the actual last build time. Maybe manually update it every time you put out a new release?