# Display the TFS server Build number in the UI of a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, tfs, build

If I look at the interface of TFS-server, under category "build & release", I can see the build number:

[image]

I want to know how can I get access to the value of the last build: **23112017-8** in my WPF application (I want to display in my WPF app - **"Last Build: 23112017-8"**). How can I get this value via C# code, for example in my view model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
string version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();  
this.Text = String.Format("Last Build: - version {0}", version);
```

The value returned from `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` is that in your project's `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

You can use the extension [Update AssemblyInfo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastianlux.UpdateAssemblyInfo) to modify the version as build number before a build to specify the value it returns.

Just use the predefined variable `Build.BuildNumber` to get the build number.

Reference :

- [How to display the running version in a C# WPF app](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-display-the-version-in-a-c-wpf-app/)
- [How can I display the Build number and/or DateTime of last build in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532705/how-can-i-display-the-build-number-and-or-datetime-of-last-build-in-my-app)

[image]