# Update AssemblyInfo.cs version from TFS (Team Foundation Server) when Checking in

Tags: tfs, version, checkin, assemblyinfo

As title says.
Is there a way to get a value from TFS like a "Build Value" which I could implement in to visual studio Forms Application upon clicking "Check In" in "Team Explorer"?

Found something like this: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=tfsversioning 
But looks too big of a project.

Comment: What's the version of  TFS do you use?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 16.122.27102.1, not sure what year it is, i think its the latest (2015?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you are using the vNext build system (TFS 2015 and later versison), then you can achieve that with **CI** (Continuous Integration) build.

1. Install the extension [Update AssemblyInfo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastianlux.UpdateAssemblyInfo) on TFS
2. Create a build definition and enable `Continuous Integration`, add
   task `Update AssemblyInfo`
3. Use the predefined variable `Build.BuildNumber` to get the build
   number and set the build number as the file version
4. Copy below command and save as a PowerShell/cmd script, then add a
   PowerShell/Command task **as the last task** to run the script to
   check in the changes. See [Checkin command](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=vsts).

   ```
   tf Checkin $source_dir /comment:"Updated AssemblyInfo.cs version" /noprompt /force /bypass /override:"bypass checkin policies"
   ```

Thus the build definition will be triggered once you check in changes and the `AssemblyInfo.cs` version will be updated automatically with the build number and the updated `AssemblyInfo.cs` file will be checked in once the build completed.

Reference below threads:

- [Display the TFS server Build number in the UI of a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484134/display-the-tfs-server-build-number-in-the-ui-of-a-wpf-application/47506059#47506059)
- [TFS 2017 vNext Build Get workspace with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47751871/tfs-2017-vnext-build-get-workspace-with-powershell/47765393#47765393)

[image]

Comment: @Edgaras Have you resolved the issue by the solution? any update?

Comment: Yes, I was able to use the "Update AssemblyInfo" before the build solution, and that seems to do the trick! Thanks!